# How to keep only alphanumeric and space, and also ignore non-ASCII?

Tags: python, regex

I have this line to remove all non-alphanumeric characters except spaces

```
re.sub(r'\W+', '', s)
```

Although, it still keeps non-English characters.

For example if I have

```
re.sub(r'\W+', '', 'This is a sentence, and here are non-english 托利 苏 !!11')
```

I want to get as output:

```
> 'This is a sentence and here are non-english  11'
```

Comment: In your example output you don't have `,`  or `!` in there but you do have `-`, what do you exactly want to keep?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', s)
```

(Edit) To clarify:
The `[]` create a list of chars. The `^` negates the list. `A-Za-z` are the English alphabet and  is space. For any one or more of these (that is, anything that is not A-Z, a-z, or space,) replace with the empty string.

Comment: note that if you need any whitespace, not just regular spaces, replace ` ` with `\s`

Comment: if you need more characters just add them after the list. If you need `-` (dash) make sure it's the last item on the list, e.g. `[0-9A-Za-z ,.-]`

Answer (score 9):

This might not be an answer to this concrete question but i came across this thread during my research.

I wanted to reach the same objective as the questioner but I wanted to include non English characters such as: ä,ü,ß, ...

The way the questioners code works, spaces will be deleted too.

A simple workaround is the following:

```
re.sub(r'[^ \w+]', '', string)
```

The ^ implies that everything but the following is selected.
In this case \w, thus every word character (including non-English), and spaces.

I hope this will help someone in the future

Answer (score 3):

I once had this exact problem, the only difference was that I wasn't able to import anything or use regex.

To solve my problem I created a list containing all of the values I wanted to keep:

```
values = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ")
```

Then I created a function that would loop through each item in the string and if it wasn't in the `values` list, it'd remove (replace) it from the string:

```
def remover(my_string = ""):
  for item in my_string:
    if item not in values:
      my_string = my_string.replace(item, "")
  return my_string
```

For example, the following code:

```
print(remover("H!e£l$l%o^ W&o*r(l)d!:)"))
```

Should output:

```
'Hello World'
```

Sure this isn't the best way to do this but given the circumstances, it was a quick and easy way to get job done.

**NOTE:** you can replace the items that ***are*** in the `values` list by changing `if item not in values` to `if item in values`.

**NOTE:** I wasn't allowed to use [string constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants) because the `string` package has to be imported to use them.

Good luck.