# Extract existing words from text that are not easily separable

Tags: python, algorithm, text, matching, string-matching

So, I have a set of "words", like:

`{'machine learning', 'r', 'python', 'neural networks', 'c', 'c#', 'docker'}`

And I have a text which contains words I am interested in (shown in bold), like:

*In general: Support us in topics related to **machine learning**/artificial intelligence, i.e. algorithm development, data preparation and processing in **Python**, **C** or C++, neural network training, deployment of **neural networks** for real-time execution, visualization of results, generation of performance statistics etc.*

The texts are about 3000-5000 characters, probably around 400-550 words long. And the set of words I am interested in currently has a length of 3000 unique "words".

---

My first version was that I normalize my text by converting all words to lower case and removing special symbols, then split it by spaces and check every word in the text if it exists in the set of interesting words and to remember those which exists in the text.

**Problems:**

- Some words in the set are themselves split by spaces. *E.g. neural
  networks*.
- Some words are substrings of other ones *E.g. C and C++*.
- Some words are also no just alphanumeric. *E.g. C++*.
- If a part of match is in another line like `neural\nnetworks`, then it should result in a successful match.

What would be an appropriate algorithm to solve this task? Additionally performance somehow matters as this is part of a web endpoint.

Comment: Check out Boyer Moore, for example, here: https://github.com/mscdex/streamsearch

Comment: You can use `regex`. Joining the list using `|`, that is, `words|more than one` and then applying the regex globally in case insensitive manner should do the trick. What language are you using?

Comment: @danh I am not sure if a substring search can be used here e.g. in the sentence "A string with some words" and being "word" and "words" the ones I am interested in, it would find both but I only want it to be "words"?

Comment: @AKSingh I am using Python for this one, with my basic regex understanding I would run into the problem that if I have "An example string with some words" and I am interested in "word" it will detect it but "words" != "word" so it should not detect it here

Comment: Build a dict `{'words': 'words', 'more': 'more than one'}` from set `{'words', 'more than one'}`, where keys are the first words of these sentences. Then split the text into individual words, and look for them in the dictionary. Remember the positions of those words in the text. When you found a word in the dict, check if the sentence actually match. For instance, when you have found the key `'more'` in your dict, knowing that the value for that key is `'more than one'`, knowing that `'more'` is at position 63 in text, check whether `text[63:63+len('more than one')] == 'more than one'`.

Comment: Before splitting the text, preprocess it using [Only keep alphanumeric and space and ignore non ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902042/python-keep-only-alphanumeric-and-space-and-ignore-non-ascii) and `.lower()`.

Comment: Also, what to do with punctuation is your choice. If `"more than. One"` is in the text, should it match `'more than one'` in the set of words?

Comment: @Greeneco *It will not match if you add a word boundary check in the end*, which can be done by enclosing all the words join by `|` between `\b`.

Comment: @Greeneco Please note that you need to be more specific of what you want to match. Should `more than\n one` match or not? Should `more than one.` and `more than. one` match? *Please make your question more detailed.*

Comment: @AKSingh I have improved the example (I guess). Sometimes words are also no just alphanumeric like `C++`. But `more than. one`should not match, but `more than\n one` should, but sometimes punctuation can be part of the word itself, e.g. `React.js`.

Comment: @Greeneco Working on the solution

Comment: @Stef this sounds promising. The only edge case I can think about is that I need to to remove punctuation but in rare cases can be part of the words I am interested in, which I need to handle. Probably if a word contains punctuation I also need to check every combination again my dict.

Comment: @AKSingh ok cool, thanks

Comment: @Greeneco a possibility is to simplify the problem by also removing punctuation from the set of words; for instance, convert `React.js` to `react js`. In theory this might result in a small number of false positive in edge cases, but with actual text it might be okay.

Comment: @Stef ah ok, yes this makes more sense

Comment: I'm a little confused as to your aim. Do you just want to know if the text contains your word/phrase? Or do you want to know where it is? Or do you want to know if it contains them all? Or count them? Also, you should add a language tag. which you must have if you have the regex tag. I suggest you remove the regex-tag, since you may be interested in other solutions than a regex solution.

Comment: @Scratte I want to know if the text contains my word/phrase. The count and position does not matter, I only want which of them are in a given text.

Comment: @Scratte I could not add the language tag as it requires a higher reputation than I currently have, but I replaced the regex tag with nlp

Comment: I don't understand how it requires more reputation to add python than nlp. Note that are max 5 tags no matter the reputation. The tags will signal which subject matter experts should look at your post. You have used "text". I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Scratte oh you meant python the prog language :D , I replaced nlp with python now. there is actually a tag called language so I thought you meant this one

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant programming language :)